# How to use a record id of a CSV file for programming?

Tags: python, csv, odoo-8, odoo

If I have CSV file that I included for seed data. Then I want to use a record inside that CSV file for programming. How can I do it in Odoo?

For example

My CSV seed file `product.category.csv`

```
id       name
ctgry_1  Custom Category
```

In my model I want to do this:

```
product_template = self.env["product.template"]
product_new = product_template.create({
    "name" : "Custom Template",
    "categ_id" : # I want to use ctgry_1 here, but it does not work
})
```

Should I first do a search for my category id? But that seemed like wrong to me. Shouldn't we be able to use the identifier from CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well you want to convert some external identifier to the database id, right? Then you just need to get the id like this:

```py
product_template = self.env["product.template"]
product_new = product_template.create({
    "name" : "Custom Template",
    "categ_id" : self.env.ref('ctgry_1').id
})
```

Anyway if you are importing data with the CSV Importing Interface you should use this format:

```
"module_name.record_identifier" > "__import__.ctgry_1"
```

You can check all the identifiers here: **Settings > Sequences & Identifiers > External identifiers**.

**Note:** If you export data the external identifier of the record is created automatically. If you import data with the external identifier (id columns), it is assigned to the record as well